# Can't print event in controller codeigniter

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter-2

I have a method to print tag html with an event, but the event can't be used because html just printed the event.

Here my code:

[image]

Sorry, i used a picture to show my code. Stackoverflow is not allowed to post a html tag. Here the result of my code:

[image]

How to fix my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a string as plain text to a JS function.

Rewrite the code in the following manner

```
<?php
    $dataPosisi = ['Pemimpin Cabang', 'Pemimpin SKC', 'Pemimpin SKM'];
    $data       = '';
    foreach ($dataPosisi as $item)
    {
        $data .= "<li><a href='#' onclick='getPicture(\"{$item}\")'>{$item}</li>";
    }
    echo $data;
?>
```

Note: If you are not using `{$item}`, you have to go for string concatenation `"<li><a href='#' onclick='getPicture(\"". $item ."\")'>". $item . "</li>"`